# Given a hash value, is it possible to determine the length of the initial string that was digested? (SHA256)

Tags: hash, sha256

Also, given two hash values, is it possible to determine if either one of them was a result of digesting a larger string?
As far as I understand SHA256, nothing but guessing the string itself helps. Though, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Given a hash value, is it possible to determine the length of the
>   initial string that was digested? (SHA256)

No. The result is always a fixed length output in the case of SHA256, regardless of input length. Therefore there is no way to know the original length from looking at the output. The hash function is designed so no knowledge of the original input can be determined.

> Also, given two hash values, is it possible to determine if either one
>   of them was a result of digesting a larger string?

No, for the same reasons as above.

> As far as I understand SHA256, nothing but guessing the string itself helps.

Remember that different input strings can, and do, result in the same hash digest (the output).

Comment: as far as two input strings in SHA256 producing same hash digest, doesn't this contradict that https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47809/why-havent-any-sha-256-collisions-been-found-yet - Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: No you are correct. No collisions have been found, but that doesn't mean they don't happen across the globe. The number of combinations of output is vast, but is still finite. It's just almost impossible to find one by looking for it. (Hope that makes sense, not sure I've described it well)

Comment: @Danny+ As the link shows (even with updated numbers) it should take bitcoin mining almost a trillion years to have one collision (but not report it), and considering ASIC is about a hundred times faster than GPU which is about a thousand times faster than CPU, the total hashes computed for everything else, with the possible exception of password breaking, is probably a much less.